# AppDelegate not key value coding-compliant for key window since ARC migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, xib

I just made the migration to ARC and since this time, my application crash on splash screen due to this error.

> [Appdelegate setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key window

I already found some answer who said than the outlet "window" is not connected properly in the xib, I tried to fix it but it doesn't work.

Also, the application is a bit old. It does not use xib file, except for a MainWindow.xib who just have the window.

I also tried to do something like this :

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
```

I deleted the outlet link in the xib file then run and got a new error :

> [AppDelegate setWindow:] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any help would be super nice :)

PS : If you need to see more code, feel free to ask

> AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : WTAppDelegate <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FSHGlobalResize *resizer;

- (void)timerDidEnd;

@end
```

> AppDelegate.m

```
@interface AppDelegate () <FSHGlobalResizeDelegate, DownloadManagerDelegate>
{
    BOOL isBackground;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) FSHHomeViewController *rootViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) FSHNavigationController *navigationController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

#ifdef DEBUG
#else
    [Crashlytics startWithAPIKey:CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] setUserIdentifier:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];
#endif

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    [application setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    [self registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kIsHomeKey];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:kIsDatabaseLoadedKey];

    _navigationController = [[FSHNavigationController alloc] init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];

    ABRouter *router = [ABRouter sharedRouter];
    [router setNavigationController:_navigationController];

    if(IS_PHOTOBOOK)
        [router match:kNavigationRoot to:[FSHPhotobooksViewController class]];
    else
    {
        [router match:kNavigationRoot to:[FSHHomeViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://photobooks" to:[FSHPhotobooksViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://collections" to:[FSHCollectionsViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://collections/:collection" to:[FSHCollectionViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://collections/:collection/:look" to:[FSHLookViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://collections/:collection/:look/zoom" to:[FSHLookZoomViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://products" to:[FSHAccessoriesViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://products/:type" to:[FSHAccessoriesTypeViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://products/:type/:collection" to:[FSHProductsViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://products/:type/:collection/:product" to:[FSHProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://products/:type/:collection/:product/zoom" to:[FSHProductZoomViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://products/:type/:collection/:product/:article/:look" to:[FSHProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://products/:type/:collection/:product/:article/:look/zoom" to:[FSHProductZoomViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://eyewear" to:[FSHEyewearCollectionViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://eyewear/:collection" to:[FSHEyewearProductsViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://eyewear/:collection/:product" to:[FSHEyewearProductViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://watches" to:[FSHWatchesCollectionViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://watches/:collection" to:[FSHWatchesSubCollectionViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://watches/:collection/:subcollection" to:[FSHWatchesProductsViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://watches/:collection/:subcollection/:product" to:[FSHWatchesProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://watches/:collection/:subcollection/:product/zoom" to:[FSHWatchesZoomViewController class]];


        [router match:@"cc://communication" to:[FSHCommunicationViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://communication/:type" to:[FSHCommunicationTypeViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://communication/:type/:element" to:[FSHCommunicationElementViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://communication/booklets/:element/:page" to:[FSHCommunicationBookletPageViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://communication/campaigns/:element/:page" to:[FSHCommunicationCampaignPageViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://communication/:type/:element/:page/:zoom" to:[FSHCommunicationZoomViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://videos" to:[FSHVideosViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://videos/:type" to:[FSHVideosTypeViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://videos/:type/:section/:video" to:[FSHVideoViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search" to:[FSHSearchViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search/:type" to:[FSHSearchViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section" to:[FSHSearchSectionViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/product/:collection/:product" to:[FSHProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/product/:collection/:product/zoom" to:[FSHProductZoomViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/look/:collection/:product" to:[FSHLookViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/look/:collection/:product/zoom" to:[FSHLookZoomViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/eyewear/:product" to:[FSHEyewearProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/watches/:product" to:[FSHWatchesProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/:type/:section/watches/:product/zoom" to:[FSHWatchesZoomViewController class]];


        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id" to:[FSHSearchReferenceViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/look/:product" to:[FSHLookViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/look/:product/zoom" to:[FSHLookZoomViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/watches/:product" to:[FSHWatchesProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/watches/:product/zoom" to:[FSHWatchesZoomViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/eyewear/:product" to:[FSHEyewearProductViewController class]];

        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/product/:product" to:[FSHProductViewController class]];
        [router match:@"cc://search/reference/:id/product/:product/zoom" to:[FSHProductZoomViewController class]];




        [router match:@"cc://history" to:[FSHHistoryViewController class]];
    }
    [router match:@"cc://photobooks/:photobook" to:[FSHPhotobookViewController class]];
    [router match:@"cc://photobooks/:photobook/:item" to:[FSHPhotobookDetailViewController class]];

    [router match:kNavigationLanguage to:[FSHLanguageViewController class]];
    [router match:@"cc://language/monitoring" to:[FSHMonitoringViewController class]];

    [[ABRouter sharedRouter] openURL:kNavigationRoot];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(timerDidEnd) name:kTimerDidEndNotification object:nil];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kIsNavigationRoot];
    [[FSHTimerManager sharedManager] setTimeSchedule:TIMER_HOME];
    [[FSHAnalyticsTracker sharedInstance] appStart];

    BOOL shouldMigrate = ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kContentDidMigrateKey] == nil);
    [[CCDataBundleMultiChannel sharedInstance] setDataBundleDirectory:CCDataBundleDirectoryApplicationSupport withMigration:shouldMigrate];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kContentDidMigrateKey];

    isBackground = NO;
    _resizer = [[FSHGlobalResize alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    if([_resizer isBatchComplete] == NO) {
        [[FSHDownloadManager sharedManager] photobookChannelWorking:YES];
        [_resizer start];
        [self performBlock:^{
            FSHNavigationController *navigationController = (FSHNavigationController*)[[ABRouter sharedRouter] navigationController];
            [navigationController showUpdate];

        } afterDelay:1];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[FSHDownloadManager sharedManager] setDelegate:self];
    [[FSHSectionsDataModel sharedInstance] deleteDatabase];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Well the *unrecognized selector* is probably because `window` is not a property of the app delegate.  What window instance variables/properties have you provided for it?

Comment: In this case just "@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;"

Comment: You should not be receiving that exception then.

Comment: Please post your AppDelegate files header + implementation. This would provide more context.

Comment: Done, I just post the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I don't know why but the line @synthesize window; is needed in this case. I removed the line myself while thinking it was useless.